# Error: Module not found Framework7

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, framework7

estoy llevando un proyecto en vue con framework7, estoy usando cordova para construir el apk, es la primera vez que trabajo con esta tecnología y no encuentro mucha informacion sobre el problema que estoy pasando.

Verá, en primer lugar, encontré la aplicación con una versión “^4.5.1” de framework7, la actualicé a la última versión “^8.3.1”, ejecuté npm install, actualicé las dependencias, también actualicé mi main.js.

```
import Framework7 from 'framework7';
```

Y precisamente en esa línea es donde me sale un error al ejecutar cordova run browser – --live-reload, que es el siguiente:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'framework7' in 'E:\repo\laragon\www\futugapp\src'
```

Espero puedan darme una mano